# How to split a spark job into chunks automatically

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose you have a dataset with 900 million records.
You run a certain query that retrieves all of these 900M records, tries to process the data and spark crashes due to memory issues.

However, everything works fine if you run this job three times, each time with 300M records each. Meaning, if you split your dataframe by a certain parameter and get it as an input in the query so you don't have to load all the dataframe at once.
For example, in the image below, if you run the job with the complete table, spark crashes. However, if you split it in three runs, spark will do the job well.

[image]

How would you automate this split? Meaning, these three jobs can separately, but I don't want to do that manually.

Comment: Why should we suppose *"You run a certain query that retrieves all of these 900M records"* if that's what you're meaning to avoid in the first place?

Comment: is your data partitioned ? in that case you can filter on the partition, this will reduce the data loaded because of spark filter push down mechanism.

Comment: I want to add one question - from what source are you reading your data?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. Here are my answers: I am reading my data from Hive. The data is partitioned. How would you filter by partition and still be able to process all of the available partitions without loading everything to memory? @ernest_k, you are right, no need to suppose anything :)